# Algumas hr's não aparecem

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho o estilo para uma `hr` abaixo:

```
hr {
    width : 100%;
    height: 1px;
    size:1px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

e tenho 4 `hr's` na página.
O problema é que quando faço

```
height: 1px;
size:1px;
```

ou

```
height: 1.0px;
size:1.0px;
```

Algumas `hr's` aparecem.

Mas quando passo para:

```
height: 1.1px;
size:1.1px;
```

em diante, então todas `hr's` aparecem.

Como corrigir isso?

Isso pode ser visto [aqui](http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos)

Comment: No link informado só tem dois `<hr>` e as duas aparecem.

Comment: Acabei de encontrar o problema: o navegador estava com zoom de 90%, quando passa para 100% o problema some.Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Problema foi resolvido pelo próprio autor:

> Acabei de encontrar o problema: o navegador estava com zoom de 90%, quando passa para 100% o problema some.Obrigado.